# Android fragment - findViewById returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have a problem that seems to be quite common on the internet : I have created an activity with just a fragment. This is the generated code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        }
    }
```

After or inside the condition, I can't get any object with findViewById: it is always null. Here is the rest of the generated code :

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

activity_customer.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.axacs.marc.CustomerActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

the listview is actually in fragment_customer.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/new_folder_button"
    android:text="" />
```

Does anyone know what is missing ?

Comment: Listview belongs to `fragment_customer.xml`.post the same

Comment: Do clean build your project. Show your activity_customer.xml

Comment: ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); move this line on fragment onCreateView()

Comment: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer,container, false);
ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
return rootView;`

Comment: Do you get the context with `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` then or is it something else?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not used to fragments but it seems my problem was very simple. I've had the same problem with a viewpager, but your solution didn't work in that case. I will post another question if it keeps bothering me. Thank you again!

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thanks. I was doing getActivity.findViewbyId(), but that also returned null. Finally tried inflater.inflate.findViewById as your solution suggests and it worked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use following after moving this line to onCreateView() if you want to use your listview in your fragment

```
ListView lv = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: `cannot resolve "rootview" symbol` :(

Comment: @dialex rootview is not a predefined symbol.Its the name given to the view that is going to be inflated in the fragment.It can have any name.

Comment: @dialex
your function->onCreateView should looks like ->
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview=null;
       
             rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);
           ListView lv = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

return rootview;